# Bluetooth service "grayed out" and unresponsive

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, pulseaudio

My dell laptop has had many issues with bluetooth in the past, including it dropping out or just refusing to turn on. It hasn't been able to connect to any devices for about a month (around when I upgraded to jammy jellyfish. I'm currently on kinetic and the issue still persists).

Running `systemctl status bluetooth.service` gives me the following error:
`bluetoothd[1000]:src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 88:D0:39:A2:C0:40: Protocol not available`

Solutions I have tried to no avail:

- Restarting the bt service from the terminal using `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
- Reinstalling an older version of `ar3k` bt drivers
- Installing  `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT an answer but I have lots of data to provide for people eventually look into this and they do not fit in a comment.

I have a similar problem - Kinetic 22.10 fresh install, pipewire/wireplumber by default.

The BT earbuds w/ mic Jabra Elite 85t generally work good but sometime it gets messy after a while I have to put them back in the box, or even restart the system.

This is what happen on a freshly boot system when I get the Jabra out the box - and they automatically connect to BT as they're paired - from `journalctl -f`

```shell
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event24)
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (**) Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP)'
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event24 13:88 fd 71 paused 0
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (**) Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): always reports core events
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event24"
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) event24 - Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) event24 - Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) event24 - Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): device removed
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input28/event24"
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) event24 - Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2440]: (II) event24 - Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
gen 25 13:43:00 tuxy14 gnome-shell[2670]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
gen 25 13:43:01 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 30:50:75:BE:B0:3D: Device or resource busy
```

Two potential issues here. First device is tagged as a keyboard...

```shell
(II) event24 - Jabra Elite 85t (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
```

And the final line is red as in error:

```shell
bluetoothd[1129]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 30:50:75:BE:B0:3D: Device or resource busy
```

If I run `systemctl status bluetooth.service` I get:

```shell
gen 25 13:34:03 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
gen 25 13:34:03 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_pro
gen 25 13:34:10 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 7C:96:D2:3B:9B:2C: Host is down (112)
gen 25 13:34:15 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
gen 25 13:40:48 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 30:50:75:BE:B0:3D: Device or resource busy
gen 25 13:40:48 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 30:50:75:BE:B0:3D: Device or resource busy
gen 25 13:41:00 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
gen 25 13:41:31 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 30:50:75:BE:B0:3D: Device or resource busy
gen 25 13:42:32 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
gen 25 13:43:01 tuxy14 bluetoothd[1129]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 30:50:75:BE:B0:3D: Device or resource busy
```

[image: This is the Sound Control panel. Jabra are properly seen as hand-free mic and using mSBC.]

Comment: Suggest converting to a Community Wiki answer and ask others to add information.  When it is (hopefully) resolved eventually, the relevant info can be edited into the question itself.

Comment: Definitely appreciate you adding the info here, but having it as a "Community Wiki" will be more palatable to some folks who might want to otherwise have it deleted.

Comment: Hi there, what exactly do you mean by converting to community wiki? I'm new to ask ubuntu and want this info to get out to as many people as possible so the bug can be fixed